# latest alias doesn't work with gcloud secrets versions destroy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-secret-manager

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/versions/destroy), `gcloud secrets versions destroy` can be invoked with the latest alias:

```
gcloud secrets versions destroy latest --secret my-secret
```

But when I do this, I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.secrets.versions.destroy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Resource ID [projects/XXXXX/secrets/my-secretversions/latest] is not in a valid format.
```

If I do

```
gcloud secrets versions describe latest --secret my-secret
```

I get a valid secret returned.

Is the documentation just wrong for the `destroy` command, or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the documentation. Let me check with the team, but I believe “latest” only applies to the access operation. It would be helpful to know your use case.

Comment: Not much more to our use case than described. We need to reset a secret in a script as it contains the wrong secret for a sensitive account (as in it's a valid secret, just not in that context). Was hoping to save the extra step of writing additional script to find the latest version.

Comment: I’ve confirmed with the team that this is a documentation bug, and they are working on a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the `latest` alias is giving the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.secrets.versions.destroy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Resource ID [projects/XXXXX/secrets/my-secretversions/latest] is not in a valid format.
```

when trying to destroy a secret using [**gcloud command  line**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/versions/destroy#VERSION):

```
gcloud secrets versions destroy latest --secret my-secret
```

This was a **Documentation bug** and it has been updated. You can't use `latest` alias to delete a Secret, you will need to specify it's `version` to delete it.

```
gcloud secrets versions destroy VERSION --secret=my-secret
```

For future, if you see any bug or not intended behavior, please click on **`Send Feedback`** button of the documentation or create a [**Public Issue Tracker** request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to investigate further and track the bug.